# Using Keras StandardScaler with Groupby function in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, keras

I have a pandas data frame with multiple columns. I need to use groupby function on each column and after use Keras StandardScaler function to transform each column in the dataframe. I tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler=StandardScaler()
df2= df.groupby('Sector').apply(lambda x: scaler.fit_transform(x.astype(float)))
```

but it returns lists of data by group, however, I need to preserve the initial structure of the dataframe.

I specifically need to use StandardScaler because afterwards I want to use it to transform testing features.

Is there a way to use StandardScaler in this case?

Comment: Please give some sample data to test. Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using group by.

To get a copy of data

```
scaled_features = data.copy()
```

To scale only a few columns

```
features = scaled_features[['column1','column2']]
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)
```

To transform columns also you can do it in your way. Or also using a query you can get only these data where the value matches your query.

```
df_c = df['column'].apply(lambda x: scaler.fit_transform(x.astype(float)))
df_cc = df[df['column'] == '...'].apply((lambda x: scaler.fit_transform(x.astype(float)))
```

Another way is to use ColumnTransformer

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ct = ColumnTransformer([
        ('name', StandardScaler(), ['column1', 'column2'])
    ], remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit_transform(features)
```

Comment: I need groupby to scale each column based on the group it's values belong too (I need to scale company financial scores and I need to group by the industry to get better results). The main problem is that I do not know how to use groupby combined with StandardScaler

Comment: So I understand that your data types depend on the industry?

Comment: for each column (some numeric score) I want to standardize values based on what industry this value belongs to (that is why I need group by 'Sector' in the code), however, StandardScaler does not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such option in the StandardScaler library but following pandas commands can be of help.

```
# Normalize around mean
df['normal'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()/ x.std()))
# Normalize between 0 and 1
df['normal'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: ((x - x.min())/ (x.max() - x.min())))
```

Regarding testing data, I think you should do the normalization before and then split it into train and test.